# Hide axd resources in asp.net MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I hide the axd, or simply rewrite the url into something else to hide the axd file?

Comment: Are you trying to provide a URL Route to the AXD?

Comment: Are you trying to hide ELMAH from serving up exceptions to the world on a production server?  If you are, you can set it up so that it's only accessible locally.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i will explain further. For some hackers to determine the web server type, they can do various check out the unique feature of the server and language. for this case, is ASP's AXD URL. how can i offusecate into something like /resource/someHash/ instead of resource.axd?=somehash . I hope this explain much further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% on what you want.  Have you the below in your route registry already.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

Comment: hi dove, can you check out my new comment in my question. Thanks :)